# Azure DevOps template as a dependency for a job

Tags: azure-devops

I use Azure DevOps Templates in Stage and I want some job to start only when Job from template is completed (**dependsOn**):

```
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - bash: |
      ...

  - template: template1.yml
    parameters:
      param1: 'val1'

  - job: job2
    **dependsOn: how to put `template: template1.yml` here?**
    steps:
    - bash: |
      ...
```

How could it be done?

Comment: is template1 a part of job1? in that case just depend on the whole job1

Comment: no, it's dedicated one, that's why I'm asking - `dependsOn: template` doesn't work - https://prnt.sc/qtojej

Comment: well, you can make it part of its own job and then template the steps? and depend on that new job

Comment: It will require template to be changed from Job template (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#job-templates) to Step template (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#step-templates) which is not bad, but doesn't feed my requirements to template functionality

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the name of the job, as it is defined in your template in the `dependsOn`.

```
#template1.yml

jobs:
- job: mytemplateJob
  steps:
  - script: npm install
```

and

```
stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
    - job: job1
      steps:
      - bash: pwd

    - template: template1.yml  # Template reference
      parameters:
        param: 'val1'

    - job: job2
      dependsOn: mytemplateJob
      steps:
        - bash: pwd
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work! But will it work vice versa - in other words, can `mytemplateJob` depend on `job2`?

Comment: Yeah that should also work. Once the template is consumed in the primary pipeline it's just as if it existed inline.

Comment: Yep, but how to make dependency inside template optional? E.g. in stage1 I'd like template to start after job1 and in stage2 to be the first "job"

Answer (score 38):

Building on [Eric Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941631/7360635) you can pass in the name of the job that the template will depend on as a parameter.

```
#template1.yml

jobs:
- job: mytemplateJob1
  steps:
  - script: npm install
```

```
#template2.yml
parameters:
  DependsOn: []

jobs:
- job: mytemplateJob2
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.DependsOn }}
  steps:
  - bash: pwd
```

By setting the default value for DependsOn to `[]` you ensure that the template will run if no value is passed in for DependsOn but you can optionally create a dependency like this:

```
stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - template: template1.yml  # Template reference

  - template: template2.yml
    parameters:
      DependsOn: 'mytemplateJob1'
```

Comment: I was seaching for the opposite of the question (my template needed to depend on some other job) and this is the perfect answer for both

Comment: I found this after running into the same issue, and this worked GREAT.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but my answer was to put the "dependsOn" inside the templates themselves.

As all the YAML is loaded together, the templates can reference each other.

So: template-A.yml

```
jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy_SQL_Database'
    displayName: 'Deploy SQL Database'
...
```

and template-B.yml

```
jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy_AAS'
    displayName: 'Deploy AAS'
    dependsOn: Deploy_SQL_Database
```

That should do what you are asking.